# Insert into a table multiple values of which one value is from another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, and I am looking for a query like this:

```
insert into table1 (col1,col2,col3) 
values (11, 23, VAL) select VAL from table2 where id='4'
```

Is this possible?

All the examples I am coming across are for inserting all the values from one table to another, so the SQL statement does not have the `values (...)` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An insert with a select, hardcoding the values of the first two columns.

```
insert into table1 (col1,col2,col3) 
select 11, 23, VAL 
from 
  table2 
where id='4'
```

Because it seems like you've confused the two, here's some additional information.

Inserts can take two forms.

1. An insert with values.

   1. `insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3) values ('val1', 'val2', val3')`
2. An insert with a select.

   1. `insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3) select col1, col2, col3, from table2 where...`

All I've done in your case is used the second form and hard coded the first two columns values.